# How trigger Function when any changes in dynamodb table using cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

How trigger Function when any changes in dynamodb table using cloudformation template

I used

"Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",

"Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",

Comment: Please share more of your template configuration. Posting only the resource type you used is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` type resource for DynamoDB Streams which will invoke the lambda function.

Assuming you have a Lambdafunction and dynamodb table resource in your cloudformation template, next step will be defining `EventSourceMapping` as in below code snippet:

```
MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: '50'
    ..............  
MyDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
      .......................
DynamoDBTableStream:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      # The maximum number of DB items to send to Lambda
      BatchSize: 1  # It can be changed based on the need
      Enabled: True
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt MyDynamoDBTable.StreamArn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
      # Always start at the tail of the Stream
      StartingPosition: LATEST
```

Comment: The event source arn (" arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:397338090360:table/DeviceSettings/stream/2020-09-03T04:21:04.754 ") and function (" CronJobFunction ") provided mapping already exists. Please update or delete the existing mapping with UUID 01b8b894-8b3d-4fe1-a4c0-f870b790739f (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 409, Request ID: dc293417-4c09-44bd-99e1-f353512b70d8, Extended Request ID: null)

Answer (score -1):

When getting the mapping already exists, you can use the following commands in the CLI:

```
aws lambda list-event-source-mappings
```

And to delete the actual mapping:

```
aws lambda delete-event-source-mapping --uuid <the uuid>
```